# How to have 2 floating divs have the same height

Tags: css, position

I have a wrapper containing an inner wrapper, and that inner wrapper contains 2 floating divs. The left one contains more content than the right one, so it's height is greater than the one on the right. What I am looking for is that both of the containers would have the same height.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kh2Fh/

My html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sub-menu">
        <div id="left-column" class="column">
            Agenda</br>
            Here I put some texte                                    
        </div>
        <div id="right-column" class="column">
            sdfdsf                          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

My css:

```
body{
    background-color:#E5E5E5;}

#wrapper{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:auto;}

#sub-menu{
    margin:10px;
    width:780px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;}

.column{      
    float:left;
height:100%;}

#left-column{
    width:500px;
    background-color:yellow;}

#right-column{
    width:280px;
    background-color:magenta;}
```

Comment: Put code in the question, too. This isn't a forum, for personal help. SO questions should benefit somebody else someday, and when that link dies the question will be meaningless.

Comment: You will find some good answers around the net if you search by [this problem's common name](http://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=css%20equal%20height%20columns&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this via CSS alone using floated elements, unless you can guarantee the height of each column (which you generally can't, with such a fluid medium as the web). However, you do have options:

1. Using `display: table-cell`: http://jsfiddle.net/8LdQk/3/. Unfortunately, this will not work in IE6 or 7. [This blog post](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout) detailing its use might be helpful.
2. Using JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/8LdQk/5/.
3. Using Dan Cederholm's classic [faux-columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) trick.

Comment: Hello Chuck. As what I am trying to do seems quite difficult I would go into your direction, but to make it work with all browsers I will just make a simple and normal table instead of two floating divs...

Answer (score 0):

use a 1 pixel high repeating background image with 500 px wide yellow and 280 px wide magenta. When one column increases in size - you get the illusion of both columns being the same height.

```
<div class="backgroundColumn">
<div>
Left column
</div>
<div>
right column
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which is Dan Cederholm's classic faux-columns trick http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/. as another user posted here.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do the trick for me. Can it be that simple? :)

```
.column{float:left;height:100px;}
```

Comment: Hello Ian. Thanks for trying to help. I am looking for something flexible. The height should be automatically adjusted. And when putting height auto on .column it is not working...

Comment: This is not a flexible solution.