# 100% Column Height using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to create a full height column using CSS, but I'm having a nightmare!

The only way I can manage it is by applying a background image to the body tag that repeats vertically, however the disadvantage to this is I'm unable to use a percentage for the column width(s).

I thought the easiest way to demonstrate my problem is by posting it on JSFiddle and seeing if anyone on here is able to help?

http://jsfiddle.net/smclintock/xZw6n/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.canvas {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
}
```

Thanks,

Steven.

Comment: what browsers does this have to be compatible for?

Comment: There's hardly any CSS question that has been discussed _less_ on the web ... http://www.google.com/search?q=css+equal+height+columns

Comment: IE9, IE10, Safari 5 & 6, Firefox and Chrome (current releases). CBroe - I've had a Google already, if I found a solution I wouldn't be posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have 2 floating divs have the same height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648007/how-to-have-2-floating-divs-have-the-same-height)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no really nice solution for this still to be honest, but you can use the table-cell css property. Not liked by everyone but it does have good browser support and works:

http://jsfiddle.net/VR9Bg/

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

.canvas {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

.wrapper {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: +1 this would have been my original solution if you hadn't beaten me to it!

Comment: Thanks, it's probably the cleanest way of doing it. People see the word table and run a mile but it's not all that bad.

Comment: thanks! I just tried this approach, and although it worked perfectly initially as soon as I introduced dynamic content using AJAX it started to change the percentages and fudge the design.

Comment: It should probably be the accepted answer in that case anyway, and create a new topic for your Ajax issues :).

Answer (score -1):

With reference a question(I dont remember),

> percentage
>
> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the
>   height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it
>   depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely
>   positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

So using jQuery, will be a good option.

```
var hei = $('.canvas').height();
 $('.sidebar').height(hei);
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/xZw6n/1/)

Comment: Please share the reason for downvotes?

Comment: Thanks for this, it is almost ideal, however if the content in the canvas is shorter than the sidebar then the sidebar won't reach the bottom of the page.

Comment: throwing jquery in is just lazy especially as it hasn't been tagged or mentioned in the question

Comment: Disagree with the downvote on this, is a genuine solution to this problem.

Comment: that's like someone asking how to do something in one programming language and then you give a solution using another

Comment: @Pete accepted.  But I want to share my view on this. Hope that is allowed here.

Comment: It is slightly off but it still stands that it's an alternative solution. Not as bad as someone asking for c++ and getting an answer in Python :P.

Comment: @smclintock Wrapping your content will be the right thing and it is Clean.

Comment: @user1671639 fair enough, I'm just fed up of people offering jquery solutions for things easily achieved in css