# Div at least as high as other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Although I am quite an experienced programmer, web development is quite new for me. So this question might be way to easy for you.

I have 2 divs aside from eachother. say leftdiv and rightdiv. I want my rightdiv to be at least as high as my leftdiv (for visual reasons) but it might be taller. my leftdiv doesn't change size but my rightdiv may. I dont want to hardcode the min-height for my rightdiv because i will be editing my leftdiv a lot. So I want a script (javascript or something) that sets the min-height of the rightdiv to be as tall as the height of leftdiv.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648007/how-to-have-2-floating-divs-have-the-same-height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#rightdiv').css('min-height', $('#leftdiv').height());
```

Fiddles:

[`http://jsfiddle.net/25dSw/`](http://jsfiddle.net/25dSw/)

[`http://jsfiddle.net/25dSw/1/`](http://jsfiddle.net/25dSw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

At its core, every time you do something that changes the height of leftdiv you need to update the minimum height of rightdiv.

```
rightDiv.style.minHeight = leftDiv.style.height
```

I don't know what you are doing that changes the height of left div, but as long as you can update the `minHeight` of right div afterward you should be fine. I mocked the full pattern up for you.

---

With jQuery. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/Fresheyeball/pen/Apwbr)

```
$(function() {
  var changeLeftHeight, leftDiv, rightDiv;
  leftDiv = $('#leftdiv');
  rightDiv = $('#rightdiv');
  changeLeftHeight = function(callback) {
    leftDiv.css({
      height: Math.random() * 200
    });
    return callback();
  };
  return setInterval(function() {
    return changeLeftHeight(function() {
      return rightDiv.css({
        minHeight: leftDiv.height()
      });
    });
  }, 500);
});
```

---

Without jQuery. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/Fresheyeball/pen/vdLfA)

```
window.onload = function() {
  var changeLeftHeight, leftDiv, rightDiv;
  leftDiv = document.getElementById('leftdiv');
  rightDiv = document.getElementById('rightdiv');
  changeLeftHeight = function(callback) {
    leftDiv.style.height = Math.random() * 200 + 'px';
    return callback();
  };
  return setInterval(function() {
    return changeLeftHeight(function() {
      return rightDiv.style.minHeight = leftDiv.style.height;
    });
  }, 500);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found out that I had "working" code but min-height contained a typo comma in it.